# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 - Rotation in place

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to rotate my triangles in Z axis, but I would to do it around the center of the triangle, not the center of the screen. I have researched a lot on that but didn't find any resolution.

Any idea of what could I try to solve it?

```
public class RendererClass implements Renderer {

FloatBuffer bufferObj1;
FloatBuffer bufferObj2;

int programObj1;
int programObj2;

int positionObj1;
int positionObj2;

int rotationMatrixLocationObj1;
int rotationMatrixLocationObj2;

int colorObj1;
int colorObj2;

float[] rotationMatrixObj1 = new float[16];
float[] rotationMatrixObj2 = new float[16];

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig config) {

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    

    float[] vertexObj1 = {

            -0.8f, 0.8f,
            -0.8f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 0.0f

    };

    float[] vertexObj2 = {

             0.8f, 0.8f,
             0.8f, 0.0f,
             0.0f, 0.0f

    };

    bufferObj1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexObj1.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(vertexObj1);
    bufferObj2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexObj2.length*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(vertexObj2);

    String vssObj1 = "attribute vec4 positionObj1;" +
                     "uniform mat4 rotationMatrixObj1;" +
                     "void main(){" +
                     "gl_Position = rotationMatrixObj1 * positionObj1;" +
                     "}";

    String vssObj2 = "attribute vec4 positionObj2;" +
                     "uniform mat4 rotationMatrixObj2;" +
                     "void main(){" +
                     "gl_Position = rotationMatrixObj2 * positionObj2;" +
                     "}";

    String fssObj1 = "precision mediump float;" +
                     "uniform vec4 colorObj1;" +
                     "void main(){" +
                     "gl_FragColor = colorObj1;" +
                     "}";

    String fssObj2 = "precision mediump float;" +
                     "uniform vec4 colorObj2;" +
                     "void main(){" +
                     "gl_FragColor = colorObj2;" +
                     "}";

    int vsObj1 = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int vsObj2 = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    int fsObj1 = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    int fsObj2 = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vsObj1, vssObj1);
    glShaderSource(vsObj2, vssObj2);

    glShaderSource(fsObj1, fssObj1);
    glShaderSource(fsObj2, fssObj2);

    glCompileShader(vsObj1);
    glCompileShader(vsObj2);

    glCompileShader(fsObj1);
    glCompileShader(fsObj2);

    programObj1 = glCreateProgram();
    programObj2 = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(programObj1, vsObj1);
    glAttachShader(programObj2, vsObj2);

    glAttachShader(programObj1, fsObj1);
    glAttachShader(programObj2, fsObj2);

    glLinkProgram(programObj1);
    glLinkProgram(programObj2);

    positionObj1 = glGetAttribLocation(programObj1, "positionObj1");
    positionObj2 = glGetAttribLocation(programObj2, "positionObj2");

    rotationMatrixLocationObj1 = glGetUniformLocation(programObj1, "rotationMatrixObj1");
    rotationMatrixLocationObj2 = glGetUniformLocation(programObj2, "rotationMatrixObj2");       

    colorObj1 = glGetUniformLocation(programObj1, "colorObj1");
    colorObj2 = glGetUniformLocation(programObj2, "colorObj2");     

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {

    Matrix.setIdentityM(rotationMatrixObj1, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrixObj1, 0, MainActivity.angle, 0, 0, 1);     

    Matrix.setIdentityM(rotationMatrixObj2, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrixObj2, 0, MainActivity.angle, 0, 0, -1);

}

GL10 gl;

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     

    onSurfaceChanged(gl, 0, 0);

    glUseProgram(programObj1);
    bufferObj1.position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionObj1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, bufferObj1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionObj1);
    glUniform4f(colorObj1, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(rotationMatrixLocationObj1, 1, false, rotationMatrixObj1, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glUseProgram(programObj2);
    bufferObj2.position(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionObj2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, bufferObj2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionObj2);
    glUniform4f(colorObj2, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(rotationMatrixLocationObj2, 1, false, rotationMatrixObj2, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `glDrawArrays` so you can alter your triangles in your code any way you want. Use simple trigonometry to rotate your vertices independently.

Comment: The trigonometry is already inside the shader, with my "rotationMatrixObj1" and "rotationMatrixObj2". The thing is that they are rotatin around the center point of the screen, not around the triangle center. Can you please post any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Rotation matrix rotates vertices around center of coordinate system.
If you want to rotate scene around some other point (x0, y0, z0) you have to do this in 3 simple steps:

1. translate scene in such way that your point will be in center of coord system (by -x0, -y0, -z0)
2. rotate
3. translate back (by x0, y0, z0)

Of course 3 steps of transformation are not needed, matrix multiplication can do this work for us.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's the solution. Just one last question, if I translate the scene, both my center of coord system and triangle (which is on the coord system) will be translated. Doing that the distance between the triangle and the center will be the same as before and the rotatio will be as before - not around the triangle center. I think I'm not following what should I do in code. Can you please just give some more details of how step 1 would look like? Rotation and translation I can figure out. Thank you.

Comment: I solved my question. I should put my triangle at the center of coord system (it wasn't) and then translate and rotate. Perfect mate, thank you.